# How to send python output back to html without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, codemirror

SO I was trying to make a code editor AND process the code form the user input like how most competitive coding websites work. I'll show the relevant parts.

I used codemirror along with Flask on python, make a code editor in the page, using js to get the user input from a button onclick and using ajax to send the code back to my python script, and say I processed my data and produced an output, and now Im stuck at trying to send the data back to the html page (maybe like in another code block showing the output to the user)

Code for the html code block with my attempt at sending data back:
py-tut.html

```
        <div class="codeblock">
            <p>Python editor</p>
            <code><textarea type="text" class="code" id="code" spellcheck="false"></textarea></code>
            <script>
                var codebox = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                    mode: "python",
                    theme: 'dracula',
                    indentUnit: 4,
                    lineNumbers: 1
                });
                {#set any values in the text box#}
                codebox.getDoc().setValue("import random")
            </script>
            <div class="console" id="console"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="submit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
            <script>
                function submit() {
                    var c = codebox.getValue()
                    $.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_code/', {c}, function(){
                        {#this is the part where Im stuck at#}
                        document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = {{ code }};
                    })
                }
            </script>
        </div>
```

And heres the code for the Flask section:
website.py

```
@app.route("/get_code/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_code():
    if request.method == "POST":
        code = request.form.getlist('c')[0]
        print(code)
        return render_template("py-tut.html", code = "code")
```

And heres how the website actually looks like:
[image]

The main problem being the fact that i couldnt send the data back to the html after processing it, I tried render_template, url_for, redirect, but everytime I click on the submit button, nothing happens.
Pls help

Comment: One suggestion: look up Javascript 'fetch', post using that modern Ajax equivalent to your url route, use promises (which fetch is one of) to handle the async response, and then JSON.stringify to capture the response data, and JS or JQuery to populate the relevant html object.

Comment: will look into it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brief, untested version. It relies on JQuery library.

The following script section of your page can be fired from an onclick event. it runs a [fetch](https://javascript.info/fetch) request. It should pick up your user-inputted code, or whatever you wish to transmit to the back-end. It is POST data, so content will be contained within the request (as JSON using [stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)).

```
<script>
  let api_submit = function() {
    fetch('{{ url_for('get_code') }}', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify($('.code').html())
    })
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( function (result) {
      $('.console').html(result.code);
    });
  };
</script>
```

This is your back-end route handling that POSTed data. The content needs to be converted from JSON. The flask render_template uses Jinja to construct the response, and this response data is then sent back to the client in the form of a python dict (one dict element called 'code'). Conveniently, in flask a dict is automatically converted to JSON in the response from the server to that POST request.

```
@app.route("/get_code/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_code():
  if request.method == "POST":
    post_data = request.get_json()
    code = post_data.get('code')
    return dict(code=render_template("py-tut.html", code=code))
  # you may need to cater for 'GET' accesses from somewhere
```

See if that works.

Comment: can you explain to me what any of those things mean? I dont know about the stringify, the fetch function, the response thing, and the contents inside the dict()

Comment: I've added some additional explanation in the answer. Some of the reading material might help if you're stuck.

Comment: I followed the coee you sent me , knowing almost all of it, however I foudn out result.code doesnt work, I believe result.code is the code render_template? so when I click submit, the same exact page with the same layout pops up on the left side instead of the code I needed

Comment: @bluends What does `console.log(result);` show you if you place it instead of the `$('.console').html()` call in the script? That will inform you about the structure of the result object, and whether its contents are ok/suitable.

Comment: Turns out for whatever reason, the dict(code= is turning the code variable that got sent into the whole html page, and all I need to do is to remove the render_template part, ending up with dict(code=code) and its working perfectly, thank you!